# how to display selected item by using array of ids in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small doubt i.e I have an array of ids (this array i got when selecting multiple items). From that array shall i display the selected items, but my array is only with ids. how can I do this
please help me.

array was like this [001,003,005,002]

Comment: Also post HTML and related code if you have any.

Comment: Those `id`s are valid in HTML5, but they're not going to be easy to use as part of a CSS selector; they will need to be escaped (assuming they're the complete `id`s, and not a suffix of some kind). Though, as noted, unless you post some code we're unable to help without making some major - and almost certainly frustratingly *wrong* - guesses at what you're doing. Seriously: show some (minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
showSelected = function(selArray) {
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var html="<ul>";
    for(i=0;i<selArray.length;i++) {
        html+="<li>" + mySelect[selArray[i]].text + "</li>";
    }
    html+="<ul>";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;    
}
```

the key answer to your question is to iterate through your array of ids:

```
for(i=0;i<selArray.length;i++) {
    //....do smth
}
```

in there you can get the text out of the selected option like this

```
// assuming you have defined mySelect before!
mySelect[selArray[i]].text
```

[working fiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/o39p7jb5/)

Comment: @jcubic Yes, I did. sorry.